# Compile Error: Invalid type: ApexStepRequest

Tags: apex, class

I am trying to follow the example in the developer guide:

(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_steps_types_apex.htm#bi_dashboards_apex_step_example_create_apex_class)

Woh can i fix this error when making a Apex Class?
Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: ApexStepRequest at line 6 column 9

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to read all of the directions carefully:

> Add two more Apex classes for ApexStepRequest and ApexStepResponse to support the Apex stocks class.
> The code for these classes, along with the stock step code, can be found in this public [AnalyticsApexSteps](https://github.com/forcedotcom/AnalyticsApexSteps) GitHub repo, in the /force-app/main/apex/common directory. This GitHub repo also contains other Apex step examples.

The remaining code you need will be found there.